# OpenGL:Can't use functions from glu.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I am trying to test some sample codes in Visual Studio 2013.

If I only use the functions from glut.h and gl.h,it can be successfully built:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glut.h>
static int year = 0, spin = 0, day = 0;
static GLint fogMode;
const int n = 100;
const GLfloat R = 1.0f;
const GLfloat Pi = 3.1415926536f;
void init(void)
{
    GLfloat position[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 3.0, 0.0 };
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                          
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    {
        GLfloat mat[3] = { 0.1745, 0.01175, 0.01175 };
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat);
        mat[0] = 0.61424; mat[1] = 0.04136; mat[2] = 0.04136;
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat);
        mat[0] = 0.727811; mat[1] = 0.626959; mat[2] = 0.626959;
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat);
        glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 0.6*128.0);
    }
    glEnable(GL_FOG);
    {
        GLfloat fogColor[4] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 };
        fogMode = GL_EXP;
        glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, fogMode);
        glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor);
        glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.35);
        glHint(GL_FOG_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
        glFogf(GL_FOG_START, 1.0);
        glFogf(GL_FOG_END, 5.0);
    }
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0); 
}
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glutSolidSphere(1.0, 20, 16);   
    glRotatef(spin, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  
    glTranslatef(2.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(spin, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
    glRectf(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glutWireSphere(0.2, 8, 8);    
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(2.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(2 * spin, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.5, 16, 8);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void spinDisplay(void)
{
    spin = spin + 2;
    if (spin > 360)
        spin = spin - 360;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    switch (button)
    {
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay);
        break;
    case GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            glutIdleFunc(NULL);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 0.5, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //gluLookAt(0.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("OpengGL Programming");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

However,if I want to use gluPerspective or gluLookAt which are from glu.h,it says:

```
error LNK2001:unresolved external symbol _gluPerspective@32
error LNK2001:unresolved external symbol _gluLookAt@72
```

I've added the needed directories into Include Directories and Library Directories,and glu32.lib/glaux.lib/glut32.lib/freeglut.lib/glew32.lib/opengl32.lib/whatever lib under linker but it still doesn't work.

Sorry for the bad English,Please tell me if I haven't described the problem clearly.

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right. So you have added libraries to the linker? Because the error tells otherwise.

Comment: Yeah,I've looked for some similar questions but none of the solutions seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you added under:(`project right click -> properties-> configuration properties->linker->input`

these two libraries : `opengl32.lib;glu32.lib;`

And you inclded:

```
#include <gl/GLU.h>
```

More over
if you want to use glut libraries and header files:

Add the path of header file here:

```
project right click -> properties-> configuration properties->C/C++->gneral->Additional include directories
```

Add the library path here:

```
project right click -> properties-> configuration properties->linker->general
```

Add the library names here:

```
project right click -> properties-> configuration properties->linker->input
```

This is working for me.

Comment: I tried but that doesn't work.What confuses me is that GL.H seems to work well but GLU.H can't be properly linked.

Comment: Actually "GLU.H" file contains "#include <GL/gl.h>" ...... Did you add this header in your code -- "#include <gl/GLU.h>"?